# Is Maw Peter's First Kill?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, avengers-infinity-war

So I know that Spider-Man is a 'no kill' hero, and in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Peter is really freaked by instant kill mode.

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Maw is shown to die after Peter comes up with a plan to space him. Within only the MCU, does this count as Peter's first kill?

Comment: First kill _ever_ like in comics, and other movies, or this particular MCU Peter's first kill?

Comment: Its quite arguable that peter actually killed him I mean sure he made the plan to fling him into space (not necessarily lethal to an alien mind), but ironman ultimately carried it out and space ultimately killed him. a bunch of 'no kill' superheros also seem to have werid exceptions for aliens (batman springs to mind)

Comment: @Ummdustry I think the one with the strongest no kill philosophy (in regards with almost no exceptions) was always superman (except in the latest film incarnation). All others had QUITE a lot of excuses and exceptions.

Comment: @Edlothiad that's like saying "guns don't kill people, blood loss kills people" or "I didn't kill [person I was strangling], oxygen deficiency killed them."

Comment: @ArcanistLupus My mistake, Spider-Man didn't pull any triggers to kill Maw. It was Iron Man who blew the hole. So I guess it was Iron Man not the vacuum, either way.

Comment: I am pretty sure Peter Parker has stepped over ants dozens of times. If not, his body has already killed gazillions of microbes.

Comment: Peter and Tony can’t have been certain it would kill Maw either, what with him being an alien. Manslaughter, and with a self-defence alibi.

Comment: He only came up with the plan, Tony was the one who carried it out. At most, Peter is an accessory to murder in this scenario

Comment: also - the question assumes Maw dies. He may not have in fact perished (though the film makes it seem that he does). Thor seems to be able to survive with no problem at all in the vaccuum of space. Perhaps Maw has the same ability?

Answer (score 3):

Ebony Maw is killed by Iron Man as we can see in the below clip and so should be counted as Iron Man's kill.

Whilst some will speculate that because it was Peter's plan it is his kill that doesn't make much sense. That argument usually falls to the leader takes ownership of the kills people under his command does rather than it was their plan so their kill. And in this case Peter is not the leader of Tony.

In *Avengers: Endgame* during the final battle

> we actually see Spider-Man activate instant kill mode and so those could be counted as his first kills.

Answer (score 0):

Peter came with the plan, but I would wager that Maw was killed by Tony, and not Peter.

After all those were Tony's missiles that blew a hole in the ship.